# Video from libvideo not saving in folder mentioned instead save in main directory

Tags: c#, winforms, filepath

I am working in winforms where videos are being downloaded using libvideo but they are not being downloaded in the folder where it is mentioned.

```
var youTube = YouTube.Default;
var video = youTube.GetVideo(link);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\Pictures" + video.FullName, video.GetBytes());
```

According to this it should be saved in picture folder but it get save in `E:\` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `\` to deliminate between the folder name and the file name:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\Pictures\" + video.FullName, video.GetBytes());
// Here ------------------------^
```